# Alphabet Pattern in C language

Tags: c

My code:

```
int main() {
   char A[3][6] = {
      "ABCDE",
      "FGHIJ",
      "KLMNO"
   };

   int i, j, x, y;
   x = 0;
   y = 1;

   for (i=0; i<=2; i++) {
      for (j=0; j<=4; j++) {
         printf("%c ", A[i][j]);
         x++;

         if (x == y) {
            printf("\n");
            y++;
            x=0;
         }
       }
   }
}
```

If I run it, it will display like this:

```
A 
B C 
D E F 
G H I J 
K L M N O
```

How can I display pattern the output like below, just by making a few changes to the code above:

```
        A
      B C
    D E F
  G H I J
K L M N O

O N M L K
  J I H G
    F E D
      C B
        A
```

Comment: Does A have to be a 2D array?  Can it be a 1D array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem like this lends itself to recursion. Since you haven't defined how many changes *"a few changes"* is, I kept your definition of `A` and threw away everything else:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char A[3][6] = {
    "ABCDE",
    "FGHIJ",
    "KLMNO"
};

void do_it(int from, int to)
{
    if (to <= 15)
    {
        int count = to - from;
        int padding = 2 * (5 - count);

        printf("%*s", padding, "");
        for (int i = from; i < to; i++) printf("%c ", A[i/5][i%5]);
        printf("\n");

        do_it(to, to + count + 1);
        
        printf("%*s", padding, "");
        for (int i = to - 1; i >= from; i--) printf("%c ", A[i/5][i%5]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    do_it(0, 1);
}
```

Output:

```
        A 
      B C 
    D E F 
  G H I J 
K L M N O 

O N M L K 
  J I H G 
    F E D 
      C B 
        A
```

Explanation:

- The `do_it` function takes two indices into the alphabet. These are linear indices, which will later be translated to lookup your strings. The string is selected by dividing by 5, and the character is selected by modulo 5.
- The padding uses a trick whereby you can specify the total width of a string with the `printf` width specifier `%*s`. You then pass `padding` as the width, followed by an empty string to be padded. That means you don't need to write a loop.
- The symmetry of the output is handled by making the recursive call in the middle of the function. Following that call, we output the same data but in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach as Learning did:
(online snippet: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/6UttAcD3qsI)

In this case we created two round, and inverted the logic of the for in the second round, but the main logic of your code still remains

```
int main() {
   char A[3][6] = {
      "ABCDE",
      "FGHIJ",
      "KLMNO"
   };

   int i, j, x, y, tx, limit, t; // t is for twist
   x = 0;
   y = 1;
   limit = 4;
   
   for(t = 0; t<=1; t++){
       if(t){
           y = limit + 1;
           printf("\n");
       }
       // if it the second round of twist, invert the logic
       for ( !t? (i=0) : (i=2) ; !t?i<=2:i>=0; !t?i++:i--) {
          for ( !t? (j=0) : (j=limit); !t?j<=limit:j>=0; !t?j++:j--) {
             if(x == 0){ // print spaces by axis x
                for(tx = 0; tx<=(limit-y); ++tx)
                    printf("  ");
             }
             printf("%c ", A[i][j]);
             x++;
    
             if (x == y) {
                printf("\n");
                !t? y++ : y--;
                x=0;
             }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: i know, the twist logic seems like brainf*ck